# How do I remove virtualbox.list from etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to update software of my Ubuntu 14.04 but there is an error:

```
malformed line /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (dist) ; access to this source denied.
E:opening etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list-ifstream::ifstream(13: Permission denied)
E: List of source could not be read
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Could you please help me to remove this virtualbox.list.

I really appreciate yourhelp.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need super-user privileges to delete that file. The easiest way would be to open a terminal (e. g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list*
```

This will prompt for your password and (after supplying the correct one) delete the pertaining files.

Comment: Hi I tried this but it is not working. There is showing error as per computer this source do not exist so it cannot be removed. Any idea? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Then I don't understand, how `apt-get` can complain about malformed content of a file, that doesn't exist. Does the original error still occur?

Comment: Hi, somehow I was able to remove virtualbox from sources.list. Now I am facing other problem. I was trying to install winUSB. I used following link and I was following all steps: http://www.upubuntu.com/2015/01/winusb-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive.html . Program was not installed because it shows some problem with packages - they are as per terminal demaged. Now I have again in sources.list - upubuntu-com-system-trusty.list and I am not able to remove it :( Could you please help me with this? THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: If you have a different issue, please [open a new question](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it easily actually:

1. `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d` - move to the `sources.list.d` directory
2. `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list*`

Comment: Hi thank you for your prompt response. I tried these steps but it always shows me that this sourse doesnt exist :(

Comment: @Pauli You may want to try `sudo rm -rf etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`

Comment: @Pauli if that doesn't work, then what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Hi, somehow I was able to remove virtualbox from sources.list. Now I am facing other problem. I was trying to install winUSB. I used following link and I was following all steps: upubuntu.com/2015/01/… . Program was not installed because it shows some problem with packages - they are as per terminal demaged. Now I have again in sources.list - upubuntu-com-system-trusty.list and I am not able to remove it :( Could you please help me with this? THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @Pauli Do you get the same error when trying the above - that the file doesn't exist?

Comment: @DevRobot you need a / in front of etc. that's the reason the path is not found -- you've specified the wrong one.

Comment: @amc OMG LOL - how did I miss that :((

Answer (score -1):

Jus enter to the root that the error gives you `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` using Nautilus and delete the file virtualbox.list

I was having the same problem:

```
E: Tipo «http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian» desconocido en la línea 1 de lista de fuentes /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vbox.list
E: No se pudieron leer las listas de fuentes.
```

Comment: -1 This won't work because the file is owned by the `root` account.